# Except on two arrays of objects

Tags: javascript

How can I do a javascript "except" on two arrays of obejcts?

I have this array:

```
arr = [
    {state: "FL"},
    {state: "NY"},
    {gender: "Male"},
    {gender: "Female"},
    {year: "1990"}
]
```

And I have this array containing the itens that I need to exclude:

```
excludeArr = [
    {state: "FL"},
    {gender: "Male"},
]
```

The desired array is this:

```
finalArr = [
    {state: "NY"},
    {gender: "Female"},
    {year: "1990"}
]
```

I tried this but its returning all elements:

```js
var arr = [
        {state: "FL"},
        {state: "NY"},
        {gender: "Male"},
        {gender: "Female"},
        {year: "1990"}
    ]
    
var excludeArr = [
        {state: "FL"},
        {gender: "Male"},
    ]
    
var finalArr = arr.filter(function (o1) {
          const [key, val] = Object.entries(o1)[0];
          return excludeArr.filter(element => {
            if(element[key] !== val) {
              return element
            }
          });
        });
        
 console.log(finalArr)
```

Comment: Pick a loop you like. :) I usually combine it with stingifying the objects for comparison. People are downvoting your question because you do not show what you have tried and explain why it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Array.filter()` method:

```
finalArr = arr.filter(function(obj){
  return !excludeArr.map(x => JSON.stringify(x)).includes(JSON.stringify(obj));
});
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
finalArr = arr.filter(obj => !excludeArr.map(x => JSON.stringify(x)).includes(JSON.stringify(obj)));
```

Comment: The arrays contain objects, not primitives, so this won't work. `{state: "FL"}` inside arr is not the same object as `{state: "FL"}` inside exclude array. You ahve to combine it with a method to compare the objects.

Comment: Thank you for that. I had missed that the question's arrays contained objects and not direct comparable values.

Comment: Thanks for posting my preferred version. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working because you're using filter in inner loop and inside your inner loop you're using `element[key] !== val` as if condition which will always cause to return some values which in turn turns true as per provided input.

You can change your code to something like this. Here i am using [**some**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check the non existence of value from `arr` inside `excludeArr`

```js
var arr = [{state: "FL"},{state: "NY"},{gender: "Male"},{gender: "Female"},{year: "1990"}]
var excludeArr = [{state: "FL"},{gender: "Male"},]
    
var finalArr = arr.filter(ele => !excludeArr.some(inner => Object.values(ele)[0] === Object.values(inner)[0]))
        
console.log(finalArr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there. You don't want to filter the exclude array, you want to check if any of the elements inside it has the same key and value of the element you're checking.

```js
var arr = [
        {state: "FL"},
        {state: "NY"},
        {gender: "Male"},
        {gender: "Female"},
        {year: "1990"}
    ]
    
var excludeArr = [
        {state: "FL"},
        {gender: "Male"},
    ]
    
var finalArr = arr.filter(function (o1) {
  const [key, val] = Object.entries(o1)[0];
  return !excludeArr.some( element => element[key] === val );
});
       
console.log(finalArr)
```